# javascript - function doesn't fire when it should

Tags: javascript

So I have a function which is meant to calculate whether or not a coupon code should be applied. The function checks the value of several divs and forms on the page to see if the code should be automatically applied.

However it isn't working. I only want to run the function if the url contains checkout (complex cms issue make me do it this way) and I wanted to know if anyone could spot any errors in the code as to why it isn't working. If anyone could help me out, that would be really appreciated.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<script>
var totalValue = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-price").innerText;
var couponHere = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-coupon-input");

    if (-1 != location.pathname.indexOf('checkout')) {

            if (totalValue > 240) {
                codeHere.value = "COUPONCODEDISCOUNT";
                document.getElementById('apply-coupon-button').click();
                    window.alert("sometext");
                }

    } 



</script>
```

Comment: `var totalValue = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-price").innerText;` probably doesnt work. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Does your `alert` fire?

Comment: Nope alert doesn't fire either.

Comment: Probably because of my reason listed above.

Comment: the Url is here:https://www-tasteebacon-com.checkout.weebly.com/?cart=561e90c39fb8a it should see if the content of wsite-price is over 240. wsite-price is the subtotal on the checkout page...

Comment: Just read what I said above, your call `var totalValue = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-price").innerText` is wrong -  the `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection - so you can't just call `innerText` on that... if you logged your `totalValue` variable before trying to use it - I'd guess it says `undefined` or `null`

Comment: Ah ok. "wsite-price" is a span class - would you know how to reference the content of the span through the class name? Sorry I am really new to JS...

Comment: The type of element is (well, sort of, but for now) irrelevant. Because the `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection - you have to reference the index you want. So your call would be: `var totalValue = document.getElementsByClassName("wsite-price")[0].innerText;`

Comment: Ok many thanks. Just so I actually am learning, does the [0] return the first value in the span class?

Comment: Not the first value, it reference the first `span` in the collection returned from `getElementsByClassName` - so if you had two DOM elements with class `wsite-price` - `[0]` returns the first found element in the collection.

Comment: Ok but I am correct in thinking that i am still referencing to the span class itself and not the class that wraps the span?

Comment: Yes - this is a reference to the span.

Comment: ok I really appreciate your patience and help :)

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection, so innerText most likely isn't a property on an HTMLCollection object. You can use the `.item()` method with an index to get the element, or use the querySelector method to get the single item.

```
var totalValue = document.getELementsByClassName('wsite-price');
if (totalValue.length > 0) {
    var val = totalValue.item(0).innerText;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm still not sure how this works. I am quite new to JS and wrote the above on my own. It is being use here: https://www-tasteebacon-com.checkout.weebly.com/?cart=561e90c39fb8a

Comment: The class element itself is a 'span' item

Comment: [here's some documentation on the method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) you should read through this then if you aren't exactly sure. It doesn't matter what type of html element it is, you are dealing with JavaScript objects.

Comment: `innerText` is not standard on elements neither. It should be `textContent`.